# Source Folder 'folder1' in project 'ProjectA' cannot output to distinct source folder 'folder2' in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ejb, eclipse-juno, eclipse-luna

I am getting this error in some projects in my workspace.
I have tried using Luna and Juno version of eclipse but there are errors is still in there in both versions of eclipse

Content of .classpath file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="folder1"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="folder2"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/WebSphere v6.1 JRE"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/com.ibm.ws.ast.st.runtime.runtimeTarget.v61/was.base.v61"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/hibernate"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/log4j"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="/ProjectB"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="/ProjectC"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/ProjectD"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="folder2"/>
</classpath>
```

There are no build path errors in ProjectB, ProjectC, ProjectD

Comment: Can you post the content of your `.classpath` file of `ProjectA`?

Answer (score 4):

There is no proper solution 
You can change that issue from error to warning in project preferences.

Under Project Properties->Java Compiler->Building

Make Sure Enable Project Specific settings is checked, Under Build Path Problems, 
change Output location overlaps source location from Error to Warning/Ignore.

You can also find some related discussion on the issue over [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=363863)

Answer (score 3):

I did get a solution on this issue:

There is a specification of which particular folder cannot be output at the time of creating the project. I renamed that folder to .old closing eclipse and , also tried deleting it as it was a sample folder.

If its a folder which is not that important rename that folder after closing eclipse and retry. 
This would fix the problem.

Comment: Ashok - you can mark your own answer as accepted as it has been some time. Thanks for sharing your findings.

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was to add this line

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.classpath.outputOverlappingAnotherSource=ignore
```

to .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove that the distinct source folder  'folder2' from the src path

GO to project build path

> go to source tab
> select the folder2 src entry
> remove it